# Remastering Ubuntu / skel

Tags: custom-distributions, remastersys

I want to remaster/customise the Ubuntu 14.04 live ISO. I did it manually (that means I do not want to use tools like uck or remastersys).

I used [this tutorial](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/LiveCD_manuell_remastern) (German) that works fine in general. The part with chroot I changed, of course, so that all runs without interaction in a script.

The CD boots fine after building the ISO in VirtualBox.

My question now is: I want to set some user-settings (e.g. .mozilla profile in home folder).

I think I should put this in `/etc/skel`. The script copies e.g. ".mozilla" to `/etc/skel` (confirmed), but ".mozilla" is not in live user's home folder (`/home/ubuntu/`).

It seems that what I copied to `/etc/skel` is completely ignored, but I do not know why. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Files in /etc/skel must be in place before first user login.

P.S.: I think what I find the problem - your script creates home directory for user:

```
sudo mkdir -p "${WORK}/new/home/xubuntu/"
sudo mkdir -p "${WORK}/new/home/xubuntu/Desktop/Anleitungen"
```

You need to use /etc/skel for this too.

Comment: Hi.  As you see:  http://pastebin.com/hZJuP6SA   I copy the folder to /etc/skel before building the iso.  It is there on the cd under /etc/skel but it is not copied to /home/ubuntu when live user starts..

Comment: _Please try this command instead: `sudo rsync -av /daten/ubunturemaster/files/.mozilla ${WORK}/new/etc/skel/`_ Please ignore this.

Comment: Can you provide output from `ls -l /etc/skel` and `ls -l ~/` ?

Comment: You mean providing the output from the booted live-cd?

Comment: First: http://pastebin.com/u3fw5MdA

Comment: Second: http://pastebin.com/DF3jcuwi

Comment: Thinking about rights... even when I change .mozilla to "777" it does not work.

Comment: What about `chown -R root:roor /etc/skel/.mozilla` ? And don't use 777 without urgent need, please.

Comment: Sure. 777 was just for testing.. you mean chown to root in live-system or while copying folders to target?

Comment: Don't use `rsync -av` Use `rsync -rv`

Comment: Ah.. yes.. I did change that (to rsync -rv) .. I noticed it myself that this was not a good idea because -a tries to keep user rights and so on... but it makes no difference.. :-(

Comment: Please read updated answer.

Comment: ah, I understand. Let me just check that...

Comment: you are my HERO !  That was the perfect idea and the solution.. it now works. Thank you so much imraro !

Comment: Have a nice day!